# How to get a relay output state with ONVIF?

Tags: onvif

There is a command for setting a relay output state - [SetRelayOutputState](https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl), but no command to get a relay output state.

One can get a relay's idle state:

```
IdleState [RelayIdleState]
'open' or 'closed'
'open' means that the relay is open when the relay state is set to 'inactive' through the trigger command and closed when the state is set to 'active' through the same command.
'closed' means that the relay is closed when the relay state is set to 'inactive' through the trigger command and open when the state is set to 'active' through the same command.
- enum { 'closed', 'open' }
```

How to determine whether a relay state is inactive or active?